# Как обновить несколько элементов в массиве?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-query

Необходимо обновить одним запросом несколько данных. Вот пример запроса:

```
db.coll.update(
  { article: 100500 },
  {
    $set: { a: 555 },
    $pull: { arr: { t: { $lt: 20 } } }
  }
);
```

А вот пример самого документа:

```
{
  article: 100500,
  a: 400,
  arr: [
    { t: 30, b: 12, n: 90 },
    { t: 10, b: 16, n: 60 }
  ]
}
```

Мой запрос:

1. Обновляет значение `a` на `555`.
2. Удаляет все элементы массива `arr`, где `t < 20`.

**Суть вопроса:**
Надо обновить значения `b` в маccве `arr`. То есть, везде где `n == 90`, значение `b` надо поменять на `777`. Как можно дополнить этот запрос, чтобы "убить сразу 3-х зайцев"?

В итоге должен получиться такой документ:

```
{
  article: 100500,
  a: 555, /* Тут было: 400 */
  arr: [
    { t: 30, b: 777, n: 90 },
    /* Тут был элемент массива */
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я полагаю, у вас есть следующие документы в вашей коллекции.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b71025973d202a52a5e650"),
    "article" : 100500,
    "a" : 400,
    "arr" : [
        { "t" : 30, "b" : 12, "n" : 90 },
        { "t" : 20, "b" : 16, "n" : 60 }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b7102b973d202a52a5e651"),
    "article" : 100500,
    "a" : 400,
    "arr" : [
        { "t" : 0, "b" : 12, "n" : 90 },
        { "t" : 10, "b" : 16, "n" : 60 }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b710d4973d202a52a5e652"),
    "article" : 100500,
    "a" : 400,
    "arr" : [ 
        { "t" : 30, "b" : 12, "n" : 90 }, 
        { "t" : 27, "b" : 16, "n" : 32 }
    ]
}
```

---

Прежде всего вы должны знать, что это не возможно, чтобы обновить более одного элемента в массиве используя метод  [`update()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) даже с опцей `multi: true` или используя метод [`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany); и все логики позади, что вы пытаетесь сделать; делать вещи более сложнее.

Лучший способ это  делать это используя [Bulk Операции](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/js-bulk/).

## Решение для MongoDB версия 3.2 или новее:

[MongoDB 3.2 не рекомендуется](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api) `Bulk()` и связанные с ним методы. Нужно использовать метод [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db-collection-bulkwrite)

Здесь у нас есть два варианта:

1. Нужно использовать агрегация чтотбы уменшать количество докуменьов которые нужно обновить. здесь в цепочке нужно только один этап: [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) где мы используем оператор [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).

   let requests = [];

   ```
   db.collection.aggregate([
       { "$project": { 
           "deleteElements": { 
               "$filter": { 
                   "input": "$arr", 
                   "as": "del", 
                   "cond": { "$lt": [ "$$del.t", 12 ] } 
               }
           }, 
           "updateElements": { 
               "$filter": { 
                   "input": "$arr", 
                   "as": "upd", 
                   "cond": { 
                       "$and": [ 
                           { "$gte": [ "$$upd.t", 12 ] },                   
                           { "$eq": [ "$$upd.n", 90 ] } 
                       ] 
                   } 
               } 
           } 
       }}
   ]).forEach(function(document) { 
       document.deleteElements.forEach(function(element) {
           requests.push(             
               {                 
                   "updateOne": {                     
                       "filter": { 
                           "_id": document._id, 
                           "arr.t": element.t 
                       },
                       "update": { "$pull": { "arr": element } } 
                   }
               }
           ); 
       }); 
       document.updateElements.forEach(function(element) { 
           requests.push(
               { 
                   "updateOne": { 
                       "filter": { 
                           "_id": document._id, 
                           "arr.t": element.n 
                       }, 
                       "update": { "$set": { "arr.$.b": 777 } } 
                   }
               }
           ); 
       }); 
       requests.push(
           {
               "updateOne": {         
                   "filter": { "_id": document._id },         
                   "update": { "$set": { "a": 555 } } 
               }
           }
       ); 
   })

   db.collection.bulkWrite(requests)
   ```
2. Используя метод `.find()`

   ```
   db.collection.find({"article": 100500}).snapshot().forEach(function(document) {
       document.arr.filter(function(arr) { 
           return arr.t < 12; 
       }).forEach(function(element) {      
           requests.push(
               { 
                   "updateOne": { 
                       "filter": { 
                           "_id": document._id, 
                           "arr.t": { "$lt": 12 }}, 
                           "update": { "$pull": { "arr": element } } 
                       } 
                }
            ); 
       }); 
       document.arr.filter(function(arr) { 
           return arr.n === 90; 
       }).forEach(function(element) {     
           requests.push( 
               {
                   "updateOne": { 
                        "filter": { "_id": document._id, "arr.n": 90 }, 
                        "update": { "$set": { "arr.$.b": 777 } } 
                   }
               }
           );
       }); 
       requests.push(
           {
               "updateOne": { 
                   "filter": { "_id": document._id }, 
                   "update": { "$set": { "a": 555 } } 
               } 
           } 
       ); 
   })

   db.collection.bulkWrite(requests);
   ```

---

## Решение для MongoDB версии 2.6 или новее:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
db.collection.find({"article": 100500}).snapshot().forEach(function(document) {
    document.arr.filter(function(arr) { 
        return arr.t < 12; 
    }).forEach(function(element) { 
        bulk.find({ "_id": document._id, "arr.t": { "$lt": 12 } } ).updateOne({ 
            "$pull": { "arr": element } 
        });     
        count++; 
    }); 
    document.arr.filter(function(arr) { 
        return arr.n === 90; 
    }).forEach(function(element) { 
        bulk.find({ "_id": document._id, "arr.n": 90 }).updateOne({
            "$set": { "arr.$.b": 777 } 
        });    
        count++; 
    }); 
    bulk.find( { "_id": document._id } ).updateOne( { "$set": { "a": 555 } } ); 
    count++; 
    if (count % 1000 === 0) {     
        // Выпольнить после 1000 операции
        bulk.execute();     
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
    } 
})

// Очистить очереди
if (count > 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

---

## Результать

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b71025973d202a52a5e650"),
    "article" : 100500,
    "a" : 555,
    "arr" : [
        { "t" : 30, "b" : 777, "n" : 90 },
        { "t" : 20, "b" : 16, "n" : 60 }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b7102b973d202a52a5e651"),
    "article" : 100500,
    "a" : 555,
    "arr" : [ ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b710d4973d202a52a5e652"),
    "article" : 100500,
    "a" : 555,
    "arr" : [
        { "t" : 30, "b" : 777, "n" : 90 },
        { "t" : 27, "b" : 16, "n" : 32 }
    ]
}
```