# Mongoose работа с массивом, добавление, удаление по поиску

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

У меня есть mongoose model:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    loginName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    hashedPassword: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    rooms: [{ _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, loginName: [{ type: String }] }]
});
```

Вот результат:

```
{
    _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a45f",
    loginName: "MegaDaddgy",
    hashedPassword: "*****",
    salt: "******",
    __v: 10,
    rooms: [
        {
            _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a461",
            loginName: [
                "MegaDaddgy"
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: "56c0d9e332f6ddc80ec7271c",
            loginName: [
                "MegaDaddgy"
            ]
        }
    ],
    created: "2016-02-14T16:21:26.272Z"
}
```

Мне нужно:
  1. искать по полю `rooms._id` во всех созданных юзерах;
  2. добавить мой заданный `loginName` в массив `loginName` в каждой найденной записи по критериям поиска в пункте 1;
  3. удалить мой заданный `loginName` в массиве каждой найденной записи по критериям поиска в пункте 1;

Пример:

1. `rooms._id : 56c0a986eeb118741109a461`
2. `loginName: "John"`

Результат:

```
{
    _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a45f",
    loginName: "MegaDaddgy",
    hashedPassword: "*****",
    salt: "******",
    __v: 10,
    rooms: [
        {
            _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a461",
            loginName: [
                "MegaDaddgy", "John"
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: "56c0d9e332f6ddc80ec7271c",
            loginName: [
                "MegaDaddgy"
            ]
        }
    ],
    created: "2016-02-14T16:21:26.272Z"
}
```

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обновить несколько элементов в массиве?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438537/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Comment: Не понял ваши требования в п.2 и п.3. - добавить и сразу же удалить значение одним запросом?